# store a date with datetime2 and use it with termcal

Tags: datetime2, termcal

I am making a class syllabus using the "termcal" package and would like to store the starting date for the first class so I can use it for different elements of the syllabus.  I am currently trying to store the date using the `\DTMsavedate` function from the "datetime2" package.

The date will show fine if you use, for example, `\DTMusedate{startDate}` within a paragraph.  But if I try to pass it to the date option for `\begin{calender}`, I get the error message "Paragraph ended before \setdate@ was complete".  Is there a way to make this work?  The MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{termcal}
\usepackage[american,useregional=numeric]{datetime2}
\DTMsavedate{startDate}{2017-8-29}

\begin{document}

\begin{calendar}{\DTMusedate{startDate}}{16} 

\setlength{\calboxdepth}{.3in}
\setlength{\calwidth}{0.8\textwidth} 

% Description of the Week.
\calday[Tuesday]{\classday} 
\skipday
\calday[Thursday]{\classday}
\skipday
\skipday
\skipday
\skipday

\end{calendar}

\end{document}
```

I would really appreciate any help with this, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, welcome to TeX.SX. It's nice to see a new user, who knows how to ask and do a MWE.

The `termcal` package only accepts dates in the format `<month>/<day>/<year>`. And the date argument of `\begin{calendar}` is not expanded before parsing, i.e. macros can't be used. The latter can be changed, but this doesn't work with `\DTMusedate'.

If you don't insist on using the `datetime2` package, then here is a solution without it.

To save the date, a simple command `\startDate` is defined, just containing the date in the correct format. And to make macros work as argument for `\begin{calendar}` `\setdate` is redefined so it expands the argument before it's parsed.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{termcal}
\newcommand*{\startDate}{08/29/2017}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\setdate}[1]{\expandafter\setdate@#1!}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{calendar}{\startDate}{16} 

\setlength{\calboxdepth}{.3in}
\setlength{\calwidth}{0.8\textwidth} 

% Description of the Week.
\calday[Tuesday]{\classday} 
\skipday
\calday[Thursday]{\classday}
\skipday
\skipday
\skipday
\skipday

\end{calendar}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Following on from Mike's answer, if you really need to use `datetime2`, you can just make sure that `\DTMusedate` is fully expanded before being passed as an argument:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{termcal}
\usepackage[american,useregional=numeric]{datetime2}
\DTMsavedate{startDate}{2017-8-29}

\begin{document}

\edef\startCalendar{\noexpand\begin{calendar}{\DTMusedate{startDate}}{16}}
\startCalendar

\setlength{\calboxdepth}{.3in}
\setlength{\calwidth}{0.8\textwidth} 

% Description of the Week.
\calday[Tuesday]{\classday} 
\skipday
\calday[Thursday]{\classday}
\skipday
\skipday
\skipday
\skipday

\end{calendar}

\end{document}
```

Here's a minor modification to [Mike's suggestion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/379812/store-a-date-with-datetime2-and-use-it-with-termcal/379862?noredirect=1#comment940323_379862):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{termcal}
\usepackage{datetime2}
\DTMsavedate{startDate}{2017-8-29}

\newenvironment{mycalendar}[2]{%
 \DTMsetup{monthdaysep=/,dayyearsep=/}%
 \DTMsetstyle{mmddyyyy}%
 \edef\startCalendar{\noexpand\begin{calendar}{#1}{#2}}%
 \startCalendar
}
{\end{calendar}}

\begin{document}

\begin{mycalendar}{\DTMusedate{startDate}}{16}

\setlength{\calboxdepth}{.3in}
\setlength{\calwidth}{0.8\textwidth} 

% Description of the Week.
\calday[Tuesday]{\classday} 
\skipday
\calday[Thursday]{\classday}
\skipday
\skipday
\skipday
\skipday

\end{mycalendar}

\end{document}
```

This ensures that the date is always in the style required by the `calendar` environment, even if you have a different date style in the rest of the document. (The change in style is automatically scoped by the `mycalendar` environment.)

Comment: @Nicola Talbot if you define `\newenvironment{mycalendar}[2]{\edef\startCalendar{\noexpand\begin{calendar}{#1}{#2}}\startCalendar}{\end{calendar}}` in the preamble, the `mycalendar` environment can be used in the text just like `calendar`.

Comment: @Mike Good idea.